# Hello . I can't get the data from Jquery datatable .Can you help me?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable

> //Name    Surname Adres   Email No data available in table Showing 0 to 0
> of 0 entries

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Adres { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
}
----
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string name,string surname,string adres,string email)
    {
        Session["Name"] = name;
        Session["Surname"] = surname;
        Session["Adres"] = adres;
        Session["Email"] = email;
        PersonModel person = new PersonModel
        {
            Name = Session["Name"].ToString(),
            Surname = Session["surname"].ToString(),
            Adres = Session["adres"].ToString(),
            Email = Session["email"].ToString(),
            DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString()
        };

        return Json(person);
    }
---
<body>
<input type="text" id="txtName" />
<input type="text" id="txtSurname" />
<input type="text" id="txtAdres" />
<input type="text" id="txtEmail" />
<input type="button" id="btnSet" value="Set Session" />
<table id="myTable" class="table table-condensed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Adres</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSet").click(function () {
            var obj = { name: $("#txtName").val(), surname: $("#txtSurname").val(), adres: 
$("#txtAdres").val(), email: $("#txtEmail").val() };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $('#myTable').dataTable({
                        data: data,

                        columns: [
                            { "data": "Name" },
                            { "data": "Surname" },
                            { "data": "Adres" },
                            { "data": "Email" }

                        ],
                        searching: false
                    });

                }
                
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

> data is not coming, how can I get it?
> I guess making a mistake in js
> I can post to data class but after i couldn't see at datatable.
> It could be a mistake at Columns
> I get an error when I write the code below
> No data available in table Showing 0 to 0
> I am waiting your suggestions.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so someone can help you. Also please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = { name: $("#txtName").val(), surname: $("#txtSurname").val(), adres: $("#txtAdres").val(), email: $("#txtEmail").val() };
               
 data: JSON.stringify(obj),
```

you convert `obj` into one string, but in `AjaxMethod` you catch multi propertys...

try with

```
public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string id)
```

and then `deserialize`  this object in C#